# Is there an equivalent to Oracle's `dual` table in AWS Athena?

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

I typically use Oracle's `dual` table to test functions that I have never used before prior to incorporating them in other queries. I was wondering if there is an equivalent dummy table in AWS Athena.

For example, I have never used Athena's `date_parse` function. In Oracle, I would do the following to test if the function works as expected:

```sql
select
    date_parse('2021-05-18', '%Y-%m-%d') as does_it_work
from
    dual
;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dual` should not be needed.  You can just do:

```
select date_parse('2021-05-18', '%Y-%m-%d') as does_it_work
```

Or if you really like `dual`, you can do:

```
with dual as (
      select 1 as dummy
     )
select date_parse('2021-05-18', '%Y-%m-%d') as does_it_work
from dual;
```